# How do I delete all substring starting with "/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/" and ending with ".log:" in a file?

Tags: grep, substring

I need help removing all substring starting with "/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/"  and ending with ".log:" in a fille.

Here is a portion of the file

```
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-12_084621.log:2023-09-12 08:46:41.270: FATAL: failed to create a backend connection 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-12_084621.log:2023-09-12 08:46:41.270: failed to create a backend connection 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-14_184833.log:2023-09-14 18:54:04.064: failed to create a backend connection 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-14_184833.log:2023-09-14 18:54:04.064: failed to create a backend connection is 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-14_184833.log:2023-09-14 18:54:04.096: 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-16_082301.log:2023-09-16 08:25:51.206: child pid 18545: DETAIL:  executing failover on backend 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-16_082301.log:2023-09-16 08:25:51.206: child pid 18607: FATAL:  failed to create a backend connection 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-16_082301.log:2023-09-16 08:25:51.206: child pid 18607: DETAIL:  executing failover on backend 
/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09-19_185855.log:2023-09-19 19:06:47.365:
```

Please suggest something with grep, awk, find or sed

Thanks

I try
`grep -Ewi 'failed to create a|executing failover' /var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09* | grep -v 'invalid PCP packet' >> filea`

but the result came with the `/var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool....` included. So I want to remove that substring from the result.

Answer (score 0):

This command finally resulted in what I was looking for.
`grep -Eih 'failed to create a|executing failover' /var/log/edb/pgpool4.3/edb-pgpool-4.3-2023-09* | grep -v 'invalid PCP packet'`

> -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression to search for multiple PATTERNS
> -h, --no-filename         suppress the file name prefix on output
> -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions

Comment: unclear how this is an answer to your problem?

Comment: this doesnt work from a file, but is instead grepping files from the expanded wildcard, and only capturing the few lines you mentioned any varying out put will not be captured.  so you need to either make your question more clear such that this answer becomes sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

simple:

`sed s'/^\/var\/log\/edb\/pgpool4\.3\/[^\s]*\.log//g inputfile > outputfile'` will trim off the string you mentioned... I changed from substring to line starting with this which maybe incorrect or need to be enhanced with a variant that is a space instead of a beginning of line.